# Перестал работать CWebUser->login()

Tags: yii

Добрый день всем! На сайте внезапно перестал работать CWebUser->login().

```
if($this->_identity===null)
        {
            $this->_identity=new UserIdentity($this->email,$this->password);
            $this->_identity->authenticate();
        }
```

работает и возвращает данные пользователя из бд, далее:

```
Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity,$duration) //Это возвращает true
```

А на самом деле пользователь не авторизуется, остается как гость, в чем проблема может быть, ник то не сталкивался?

З.Ы. Самое интересное, я скопировал этот же сайт абсолютно на другой хостинг там авторизация работает, а в данном нет хотя код один и тот же.

В сессию не сохраняет вот главная причина.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здравствуйте! Скорее всего дело в настройках сервера. Но чтобы удостовериться, попробуйте сменить в Yii способ хранения сессий на [yii\web\DbSession](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-dbsession.html) (это для Yii2, в первом тоже можно хранить сессии в базе, но не помню как провайдер называется) и посмотрите, будет ли сессия нормально работать при таком раскладе.

Если будет, то дело точно в настройках. Возможно указана неверная папка для сессий или есть какие-то ограничения.

ЗЫ: Оветил бы просто комментарием, но не хватает баллов.

ЗЫ2: И на всякий случай посмотрите логи сервера, возможно там будут записи, которые смогут помочь.

Comment: Ведь, действительно, сейчас изменил так чтоб в бд сохранились сессии, сработала. Значить с файлом хранении для сессии проблемы. Будем туда копать теперь:) Спасибо за ответ.